# Even after smart uv project, i cant texture paint above the white line

Tags: 3d, textures, blender

im new to blender, like a few months. The body was made of subdivided cubes which were joined together. I used a brush to paint the hairs. I uv unwrapped it and i cant texture paint some of the body

I used image texture, and smart uv project, and couldnt paint some parts.

[body texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl112.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.